# how do I get an array of the options of a SimpleXMLElement SELECT element?

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the SimpleXMLElement object for a SELECT element in my HTML.

I want to check the SELECT has the expected options, so I'd like to get an array of them. I don't need to know which one is selected.

Is there a more graceful way than:

```
$options = (array) $element->option;
unset($options['@attributes']);
```

Comment: Why do you need them as an array? foreach($element->option as $option) and similar will work fine due to the "magic" of SimpleXML.

Comment: Because I want to compare it to the array of expected options. I'm writing tests.

Comment: In that case your approach may not work anyway, as you will still have an array of objects, so a simple == will never return true. You'll probably need to loop through comparing the values as strings, which you can do without the array conversion.